# How can i set the start date as default end date if the user does not enter the end date in jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

```
var dates = $("#filterDateStart, #filterDateEnd").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
            var option = this.id == "filterDateStart" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",

                    instance = $(this).data("datepicker"),
                    date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                        instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                        $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                        selectedDate, instance.settings);
            dates.not(this).datepicker("option", option, date);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
$("#filterDateStart").datepicker({
    onSelect: function () {
       var dateObj = $(this).datepicker( 'getDate' );
       $("#filterDateEnd").datepicker( "option", "defaultDate", dateObj);
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

HTML for test:

```
<form id="testForm" action="#">
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="filterDateStart" /></p>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="filterDateEnd" /></p>

<input type="submit" value="check end date default "/>
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#filterDateStart").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onSelect: function () {
           var startDate = $(this).datepicker( 'getDate');
           var endDate = $("#filterDateEnd").datepicker( 'getDate' );
           if($("#filterDateEnd").datepicker( 'getDate' ) == null || startDate > endDate)
           {
               $("#filterDateEnd").datepicker( "setDate", startDate );
           }
        }
    });
    $("#filterDateEnd").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1
    });

    $("#testForm").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        alert( $("#filterDateEnd").datepicker("getDate"));
    })
});
```

EDIT 2:
[Working FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mEEjR/2/)

Comment: when you select anything for a start date, the end date should automatically become the same as the start date on a single click.
if you edit the start date to be > than the end date, the end date should automatically become the start date.
if you edit the start date to be < than the end date, and lower than what you might have previously had for the start date, the end date shouldn't get impacted.

Comment: Check another edit.
First of all you didn't asked to implement this functionality at the beginning and second you could try a little but harder to solve the issue and edit my previous answer by yourself the logic is very clear!